# Flutter; Passing Set<Marker> _markers = {} from one screen to another

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm making a flutter app that adds markers to a map based on the current location. I have an info screen that takes user info and passes that info to a marker to be added on the flutter google maps. I'm having issues passing the Set of markers to my map_view.dart. The following is the Future function for adding markers to the map from the current location and then navigating to the map screen with the _marker set declared in the

making a Future function called _addMarker() which would get the user's current location, place a marker on that point, and navigate back to the map_view.dart screen

info_window.dart screen.

```
    final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
```

```
    Future<void> _addMarker() async {
    getUserCurrentLocation().then((value) async {
      //print(value.latitude.toString() + " " + value.longitude.toString());
      String ID;
      // marker added for current users location
      int x = 2;
      x + 1;
      ID = x.toString();

      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(ID), //this can be taken from the other screen maybe
        position: LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'My Current Location',
          snippet: 'captured from info window too',
          onTap: () => _goToInfoScreen(),
        ),
      ));
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MapSample(_markers),
          ));
    });


        setState(() {
          //_markers = result as Set<Marker>;
        });
        //});

      }
```

And have this for my map_view.dart screen trying to get the marker set to be used in this screen

map_view.dart screen

```
class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  //Set<Marker> markers = {};

  const MapSample(Set<Marker> marker, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

//late final Set<Marker> _markers;

//marker = MapSample(_markers);

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
...
```

I'm struggling with using this variable after it gets passed to this screen, when trying to use the marker variable to add the markers to the map they never appear. Is there another/any way I should be retrieving the set in the map_view.dart screen after it's passed in from the navigator on the info_window.dart screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variables inside State class that is coming from main class that extends `StatefulWidget`, you need to use `widget.variable`. In your case it is `widget.marker`.

```
class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  //Set<Marker> markers = {};

  const MapSample(Set<Marker> marker, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

//late final Set<Marker> _markers;

//marker = MapSample(_markers);

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {

  late Type foo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    foo = widget.foo;
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to make a variable named marker for this? also I tried and implementing and its getting errors saying that the instance member 'widget' cant be accessed by an initializer.

Comment: You don't need to assign it to a new variable. You can directly call widget.marker inside your `State` class build method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that you can call it inside build method or `initState`

Comment: I figured out the widget cant be accessed problem, but now its saying "The getter 'marker' isn't defined for the type 'MapSample'.
Try importing the library that defines 'marker', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'marker'." Is this because its not declared beforehand?

Comment: Can you share where did you declare `marker`?

Comment: marker is defined in the MapSample(Set<Marker> marker,...) so it can accept that parameter, and the value that is being used for this parameter is defined in the info_window.dart screen seen at the top of the first fragment of code then is sent to the Map_view screen in the _addMarker function. Do I need to declare a variable and set it to the marker in MapSample(). The marker isn't defined in the map_view screen but the info_window and with brakepoints I confirmed the value gets sent but using that value is still the issue.

Comment: I was able to get it working the solution was a easier than I thought I needed to define marker as MapSample(this.marker, ...) then define it under as Set<Marker> marker = {}. after this I was able to use this value with the widget.merker in the build method, Thanks for the help